# Replacing "|" with "," using VB Script

Tags: loops, vbscript

```
   Dim sFile
    sFile = "File Name"

    Dim RecCount
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


    RecCount = 1
    Set objFileRead = objFSO.OpenTextFile(sFile,1)
    Do Until objFileRead.AtEndOfStream
    'Set objFileRead = objFSO.OpenTextFile(sFile,RecCount)
     'RecCount = RecCount + 1
    text = objFileRead.ReadLine
     set objFileWrite = objFSO.OpenTextFile(sFile,2)
    objFileWrite.WriteLine(replace(text, "|", ","))
  '  objFileRead.close
      RecCount = RecCount + 1
     loop
      objFileRead.close
      objFileWrite.Close
      Msgbox " files processed"
```

This code only changes the first line and erases rest of the 2000
lines.
Anything to be changed on the loop?
Please help

Comment: Any reason why you want to do this line by line?

Comment: If I execute that code I'm getting an error "Permission denied" as was to be expected if you are reading from a file and at the same time try to be writing to it. Please make sure you make an actual minimal reproducable sample demonstrating the problem https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't replace entire file content using `ReadLine` and `WriteLine` methods. Create another output file as follows:

```
Option Explicit
Dim sFile, sFileOut
sFile    = "D:\pshell\SO\Journals\test2.csv"
sFileOut = "D:\pshell\SO\Journals\test2Comma.csv"

Dim RecCount, objFSO, objFileRead, objFileWrite, text
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
RecCount = 0

Set objFileRead  = objFSO.OpenTextFile(sFile,1)
Set objFileWrite = objFSO.OpenTextFile(sFileOut,2,true)

Do Until objFileRead.AtEndOfStream
    text = objFileRead.ReadLine
    objFileWrite.WriteLine(replace(text, "|", ","))
    RecCount = RecCount + 1
Loop
objFileRead.Close
objFileWrite.Close
Wscript.Echo "records processed " & CStr( RecCount)
```

**Output**:

```
cscript //NoLogo D:\bat\SO\62676742.vbs && type "D:\pshell\SO\Journals\test2*.csv"
```

> ```
> records processed 8
>
> D:\pshell\SO\Journals\test2.csv
>
>
> "Name"|"AtBats"|"Hits"
> "Ken Myer Jr."|"43"|"13"
> "Pilar Ackerman"|""|"11"
> "Jonathan Haas"|"37"|"17"
>
> D:\pshell\SO\Journals\test2Comma.csv
>
>
> "Name","AtBats","Hits"
> "Ken Myer Jr.","43","13"
> "Pilar Ackerman","","11"
> "Jonathan Haas","37","17"
> ```

As an alternative, use `ReadAll` and `Write` methods to replace entire file content as follows:

```
Option Explicit
Dim sFile
sFile    = "D:\pshell\SO\Journals\test62676742.csv"

Dim RecCount, objFSO, objFileRead, objFileWrite, text
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objFileRead  = objFSO.OpenTextFile(sFile,1)
text = objFileRead.ReadAll
objFileRead.Close

Set objFileWrite = objFSO.OpenTextFile(sFile,2,true)
objFileWrite.Write(replace(text, "|", ","))
objFileWrite.Close

Wscript.Echo "file processed"
```

**Output** (the initial `copy` re-establishes input file with ˙|˙ *vertical lines*):

```
copy /Y "D:\pshell\SO\Journals\test2.csv" "D:\pshell\SO\Journals\test62676742.csv"
```

> ```
>         1 file(s) copied.
> ```

```
cscript //NoLogo D:\bat\SO\62676742b.vbs && type "D:\pshell\SO\Journals\test6*.csv"
```

> ```
> file processed
>
> D:\pshell\SO\Journals\test62676742.csv
>
>
> "Name","AtBats","Hits"
> "Ken Myer Jr.","43","13"
> "Pilar Ackerman","","11"
> "Jonathan Haas","37","17"
> ```